# What does `@<Plug>` mean in a mapping?

Tags: key-bindings, nmap

I have `vimwiki` and `vim-vinegar` and they conflict on an `nmap`. Calling `map -` shows these two maps:

```
n  -            @<Plug>VimwikiRemoveHeaderLevel
n  -             <Plug>VinegarUp
```

`unmap` only removed the `vinegar` map, and subsequent unmaps didn't touch the other map. What I actually wanted to is to unmap the `vimwiki` map. What does the `@` mean in front of `<Plug>`? How can I remove a mapping like that? Could I specifically unmap just this one map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `:help map-listing`, so we know `@` signifies a buffer-local mapping (`<Plug>` is its own thing: `:help <Plug>`).

To unmap a buffer-local mapping, you have to pass `<buffer>`: `:nunmap <buffer> -` (`:help map-buffer`).

Comment: Thanks, I never found `map-listing` in help.